# prevent dispatch function from overwriting current state

Tags: reactjs, state, dispatch

My context is based and a structure with either nested and not nested objects.

```
const initialState = {
  async: null
  user: {
    staticStateData: {},
    someChangingData: [...]
  }
  msg: 'some message'
}
```

I came up with the idea of having just two dispatch functions.

```
dispatch({ type: 'ASYNC' , payload: {
  url: '',
  method: '',
  values: ''
}})
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  // async function
  await useFetch(state.async.url, state.async.method, state.async.values)
  if (rsponse.status === 200) dispatch ({ type: 'UPDATE', payload: response.data })
}, [state.async])
```

```
case 'UPDATE': {
  return {
    ...state,
    user: {
     ...state.user
     // reponse.data could include some userData here
    },
    ...action.payload // this does not work
  }
}
```

useEffect updates correctly but how do i prevent the nested state from overwriting?